# Unexpected token error in react-leaflet when rendering the component for unit test case

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-leaflet

Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

```
  1 | import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
> 2 | import { MapContainer, GeoJSON, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
```

Here is my test component:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import LeafletMap from '../_LeafletMap';

describe('Leaflet Map Component', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    render(<LeafletMap />);
  });
});
```

Complete Error Log:

```
 FAIL  src/components/LeafletsMap/__tests__/_LeafletMap.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    D:\leaf\mapcomponent\node_modules\react-leaflet\lib\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { useMap, useMapEvent, useMapEvents } from './hooks.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      1 | import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
    > 2 | import { MapContainer, GeoJSON, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
        | ^
      3 | import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
      4 | import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
      5 | import { RootState } from '../../redux/store';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/LeafletsMap/MapComponent.tsx:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                      
Tests:       0 total                                                                                                                                
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.758 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Answer (score 2):

I just use a regex to ignore patterns, it's worked for me. But I'm looking for a better solution.

```
"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!react-leaflet)/\"",
```

Answer (score 0):

In the package.json file, to get my tests with react-leaflet passing I also had to add a rule

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```